# How fast does a long object bent at the center need to be travelling in order to boomerang?

Tags: kinematics, projectile, rotational-kinematics, speed

At an angle, of course.

Standard pressure, average temperature, and calm wind.

Bonus question: Can an object that is not bent boomerang at all? If yes, how different would the equations for this case be?

Comment: "Boomerang" is a noun but you use it here as a verb. Are you imagining a flying bent object turning back simply because it is bent?

Answer (score 0):

Your question implicitly assumes that a any object will "boomerang" (you mean return to thrower I guess) only depending on the rotation speed.

This is not the case. In very simplistic terms, the boomerang motion depends on its shape and material, besides on its speed. Actually even the speed is not as simple, because it needs a proper combination of translational and rotational speed to work, and of course they will depend on the shape and material of the boomerang as well.

You're right on expecting that air conditions (medium conditions in general) will affect the motion of the boomerang. But the final result is a combination of precession + translation movement of an aerodynamic-shaped object.

Thus there are more variable to account for in your question than just the speed and the angle of bending. Here as [interesting read](https://plus.maths.org/content/unspinning-boomerang) I found in a quick search.